# bash - math multiple integer with float type

Tags: bash

In bash,I am trying to do math with a integer and a float number to get a integer result. below code snippet doesn't work:

```
x=25
y=0.2
z=$((x*y))
echo $x*$y=$z
```

The error message is:

```
sh: line 3: 0.2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".2")
```

If both variable is integer, it works fine.

How can I get "25*0.2=5" from bash script?

Comment: `bash`  doesn't support floating point arithmetic. Use `bc` or `awk` or `perl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your printout in quotes in echo. Also your z=$((x*y)) will make z empty or error:

> 25*0.2: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is
>   ".2")

So... Here is tested code and might be like this:

```
x=25
y=0.2
z=$(echo $x*$y | bc)
echo "$x*$y=$z"
```

result will be like this:

```
25*0.2=5.0
```

Note: we used **bc** command for z calculation

Answer (score 0):

Try **bashj** (a bash mutant with java support) https://sourceforge.net/projects/bashj/.

for instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/bashj
echo Math.cos(0.5)
echo Math.hypot(3.0,4.0)
```